# Matching multiple values for a variable to one value to from another dataframe

Tags: r, matching

I have two data frames that I want to match and then have it return a value based on this match.

```
dt1
Name
Matt
John
Steven
Natalie, Nat
Unknown

 dt2
 Names           Grade

Matt              A
John              B
Steven            C
Natalie           D
 Nat              D
Unknown           NA
```

What I want R to do is to match dt1 to dt2 and then return a value afterwards. I've used this code:

```r
Merge_df$"Match_name" <- ifelse(df1$"Name" %in% df2$"Names","Right Name",ifelse(grepl    ("Unknown", dt1$"Name", ignore.case = FALSE), "Unknown", "NA"))
```

Desired output

```
Merge_df
A
B
C
D
E
Unknown
```

However what I get isn't this.  In the cell that has two names in it, it returns NA because it doesn't read both names, it just tries to match the whole value to dt2 which of course doesn't have any value for it (both Natalie, Nat together). I want R to read both names and see if it is both in dt2 then return the text value "Right name".

Any thoughts?

Comment: By using a fuzzy-match, you have the potential of returning more rows than either frame possesses, is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks R2evans.  No that's not my intention. Is my code above doing that?  Sorry I should have stated that I'm completely a newbie (Physician trying to be a programmer).  But is there a way to do what I'm asking above?

Comment: Okay, I think I misread it. How do you intend to deal with the multi-name row? Is that an `all` or `any` operation? (I say that because `Natalie, Nat` is not in `dt2` but your output suggests that it is.)

Comment: That's where I'm having issues...I'm not sure how to do the multiple names in one cell.  How do I have R read both names individually and compare it to dt2 and determine if they are in dt2 or not? The code works fine when only one name is in the cell but fails when there two or more in it.

Comment: Why is `Steve` matching `Steven`?

Comment: typo...I've edited it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute-force method:

```r
dt1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep="|", text="
Name
Matt
John
Steven
Natalie, Nat
Unknown")

dt2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Names
Matt
John
Steven
Natalie
Nat
Unknown")
```

(I should note that my use of `sep="|"` was solely to get the data in to this example quickly. Some alternative for `sep=` is required since there is a space in one of the fields. I could also have used `readLines`.)

First, you weren't certain how to deal with comma-delimited names. `split` can be used here:

```r
strsplit(dt1$Name, "[ ,]+")
# [[1]]
# [1] "Matt"
# [[2]]
# [1] "John"
# [[3]]
# [1] "Steven"
# [[4]]
# [1] "Natalie" "Nat"    
# [[5]]
# [1] "Unknown"

sapply(strsplit(dt1$Name, "[ ,]+"), function(s) any(s %in% dt2$Names))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Which means a nested `ifelse` looks like this:

```r
ifelse(grepl("Unknown", dt1$Name, ignore.case = FALSE), "Unknown",
       ifelse(sapply(strsplit(dt1$Name, "[ ,]+"), function(s) any(s %in% dt2$Names)),
              "Right Name", "NA"))
# [1] "Right Name" "Right Name" "Right Name" "Right Name" "Unknown"
```

(and assign that to a column).

I hope your problem is not any more complex ... as soon as I start nesting `ifelse`, I really think about data structure that can be simplified with a `merge`. To do that, you'd need to reshape (embedded to long) your `dt1` so that you don't have comma-delimited fields.

---

## Alternative

Having comma-delimited *independent* categories in one cell can be annoying from an data-efficiency standpoint. I suggest we expand `dt1` so that you have one `Name` per row. However, in order to "remember" the group from which each came, we'll assign an id to them.

From there, it's a simple matter of merging/joining them. I'll demonstrate using `dplyr`, though the same steps can be done almost as directly in base or `data.table`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest


dt1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep="|", text="
Name
Matt
John
Steven
Natalie, Nat
Unknown")
dt2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Names Grade
Matt A
John B
Steven C
Natalie D
Nat D
Unknown NA 
")

dt1 %>%
  mutate(
    id = row_number(),
    Name = strsplit(Name, "[ ,;]+")
  ) %>%
  unnest(cols = Name) %>%
  left_join(dt2, by = c(Name = "Names"))
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Name       id Grade
#   <chr>   <int> <chr>
# 1 Matt        1 A    
# 2 John        2 B    
# 3 Steven      3 C    
# 4 Natalie     4 D    
# 5 Nat         4 D    
# 6 Unknown     5 <NA>
```

With this, you can *choose* to re-aggregate `dt1` based on `dt1$id` if you'd like.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202764/discussion-on-answer-by-r2evans-matching-multiple-values-for-a-variable-to-one-v).

Comment: Many thanks! I’ll give it try after tomorrow and get back to you. Best.

Comment: nah, the other user didn't have 20 rep. Mods get an auto-flag when there are 25 comments on a post.